# Show local XML data in listview (Item and subitem)

Tags: android, xml, listview

I need to show in a listview content of a local xml file, which contains item and subitem, can anyone cite an example of how to do? I found examples that take a xml file from a URL, but want to do it locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try it .it will help you.

private void xmlPullParser()
    {
        XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.words);
        try {
            while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("word")) 
                        items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));

```
            }
            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

make folder at res like

-

Comment: No, show me a simpler example? reading the xml file that is inside the project?